# "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT" in photoslibrary.googleapis.com

Tags: ios, react-native

{
"code": 403,
"message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"service": "photoslibrary.googleapis.com",
"method": "google.photos.library.v1.PhotosLibrary.ListMediaItems"
}
}
]
}

I am accessing Google photos using API https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems

It is working fine in android. But throws an error in IOS only.

fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems', {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
Accept: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
Authorization: `Bearer TOKEN`,
},
})

Scope is already added in consent screen.

Comment: android and ios have different client id configurations to generate access token, can you check it.

Comment: Yes, for the Android I have used web client id as per the document and for IOS I have used iOS client id itself

Answer (score 0):

You    need    to    authorize    below    api's    for    getting    authorization    of    google    photos.

[photos library readonly](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly)

[photos library](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary)

[photoslibrary readonly appcreateddata](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly.appcreateddata)